# Exclude property from Template

Tags: typescript

I have this code where I can exclude a property from an interface

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

interface MyType {
  id: string
  timeout: number
  delta: number
}

let value: Omit<MyType, 'id'> = {
  timeout: 10,
  delta: 5,
}
```

That works OK, but I cannot exclude the property from a generic type, like this:

```
function foo<T>(x: T) {
  let value: Omit<T, 'id'> = {
    timeout: 10,
    delta: 5,
  }
}
foo<MyType>({ timeout: 10, delta: 5 })
```

Now I get the error message `Type '"id"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof T'` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the compiler can't check based on function declaration alone if type `T` actually has the property `id`. We can add a constraint to tell the compiler that what will be passed in will have an `id` property:

```
function foo<T extends { id: string }>(x: Omit<T, 'id'>) {
    let value: Omit<T, 'id'> = x;
}
foo<MyType>({ timeout: 10, delta: 5 })
```

You'll notice I did not initialize the `value` variable inside the function with an object literal, this is because you can't create an object literal if you don't know the full type. All we know about `T` is that is has and `id` property, we don't know anything about the other properties `T` has, what type they have and if they are required.

If you really need to initialize a variable of a generic type inside your function the only (**unsafe**) way to do this is with a type assertion:

```
function foo<T extends MyType>(x: Omit<T, 'id'>) {
    let value = {
        timeout: 10,
        delta: 5,
    } as unknown as Omit<T, 'id'> // replace unknown with any for ts before 3.0
}
```